# how to replace namespace in OSB?

Tags: namespaces, osb

I have one query.

In osb i have one service different versions v1 & v2. I need to convert data of v1 to v2 (request) and v2 to v1 (response). By using java callout it transformation is fine. But when I’m transforming v1 to v2 & v2 to v1 the namespace (body and header part) are not changed it's not converting.

In this case I need to replace namespace (body & header) or remove namespace and add new namespace. Please make a suggestion to me.

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0):

Rename action should do it which can be used to rename element and namespace.

Click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/admin.1111/e15867/proxy_actions.htm#OSBAG1142) for reference.

Comment: Hi Deepak, i tryed rename in this case can you please elaborate rename in this case i have query on xpath (rename)